# Getting CoordinatorLayout to work with a Header and a RecyclerView beneath

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

It doesn't want to inflate my CoordinatorLayout.  Logcat complains:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{....}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class CoordinatorLayout
```

I've searched overflow and added the design library dependency in build.gradle, but still it complains.  What is making it do this and how do I solve it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/primary_info"
        layout="@layout/primary_detail_info"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"

        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:text="Test text"
        tools:text="Chappie" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview_movie_details"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"/>    
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

build.gradle:

```
    dataBinding.enabled = true
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.5.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}
```

Comment: use <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout> and do not forget to add gradle dependency as well

Comment: Thanks nomag, just tried that, still throws the error, now says: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

Answer (score 1):

Add to the build.gradle `implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'` and `implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'` and sync the project

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/primary_info"
        layout="@layout/primary_detail_info"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"

        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:text="Test text"
        tools:text="Chappie" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview_movie_details"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Got that in there Laura, it's still throwing the error, thanks for your attention.

Comment: Could you please post the code you have in the build.gradle file? Thx

Comment: Done that, thanks for sticking with me.  I'm really keen on getting this working this work, rather than switching in the adapter, because the data for the header and the recyclerview is drawn from 2 different sources, a db and a network request,  and so switching in the recyclerview adapter will be complex.

Comment: Try to add  implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0' also. Please let me know if the error persists.

Comment: Yep thanks Laura!  I actually added that to the wrong project, hence why it was failing.  Thanks a zillion.